# FabricJs image is cropped when using scaleToHeight

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to scale an image so that it fits into the available canvas when using the `scaleToHeight` method the image is being cropped.  So for example:

[image: Cropped image example]

The FabricJS canvas is 1024x768, and the image resolution is 4149x2761.  I cannot for the life of me figure out why the image is being cropped.  Here is the code:

```
    _currentImage = new Image();
    _currentImage.src = "images/7.jpg";

    _currentImage.onload = function () {
        var img = new fabric.Image(_currentImage, {
            selectable: false,
            top: 0,
            left: 0

        });
        //img.scaleToWidth(1024);
        img.scaleToHeight(768);



        //img.width = _fabricCanvas.width;
        _fabricCanvas.add(img);
    };
```

If I scale to the canvas width only, the image is not cropped, but obviously fails to fill the canvas correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is perfectly normal as you are asking for a scale factor to keep the original ratio of your image. If the destination container don't have the same ratio as the image, then the image in the container will be cropped.

as you can see in this short snippet image and canvas ratio are not the same:

```js
console.log("canvas ratio:" + 1024/768 + " image ratio: " + 4149/2761);
```

use:

```
 img.scaleX = canvasWidth / img.width
 img.scaleY = canvasHeight / img.height
```

or

```
  img.set({
    scaleX: canvasWidth / img.width,
    scaleY: canvasHeight / img.height
  })
```

**Warning** you will loose the original ratio of your image.

Comment: img.setHeight is not a method, apparently,  if I use img.height=768; and img.width=_fabricCanvas.width; then the canvas only displays the very top left of the image.

Comment: Named accessors are optional in build.

Comment: @Durga I guess I'll have to answer the same as you thanks for the info, I usually use this kind of syntax for my own apps